# Jmeter Regex expression to get value from 2 lines

Tags: regex, jmeter

I need to get the value of ID using a regex.

> "yr" : "2020",((.*?\n){2})

using this I get "id" : "2221111111",
I only want to get number for id. 
How do I get that. Thanks

This is the text I want to get the id from. Id is in line 2

> "yr" : "2020",
>         "id" : "2221111111",

Answer (score 0):

You need something like this:

```
var test = {
    "yr" : "2020", 
    "id" : "2221111111",
};

var str = JSON.stringify(test);

var matches = str.match(/"id"."\d+"/g);
var id = matches[0].replace(/\D/g,'');

console.log(id); // 2221111111
```

[Snippet is here](https://plnkr.co/edit/z5tw4mjjE9guz3lg3hWg?p=preview)

Comment: I have to apply regex on json code. How can I improve this "yr" : "2020",((.*?\n){2}) to get the value of id. Thanks

Comment: I've shown you the solution, transform JSON to string by stringify function and apply my regular expressions

Answer (score 0):

```
"yr" : "2020", "id" : "(\d+)",
```

This might help you to extract value of id i.e. 2221111111 and if your "id" : "2221111111", is in next line then

```
"yr" : "2020",\n"id" : "(\d+)",
```